# What is the name / code for this plastic piece?

Tags: plastic, clips, duster

It is a plastic support for this pair of ducts on the engine of Dacia/Renault Duster 2.0.

I need the name or the piece code.

[image: Duster F4R engine]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It may have a specific name, but really it's just a clip. To figure this out, your best bet is to go to a dealership. They have blow apart diagrams which show the bits, pieces, and part numbers. Your second best option if you need one, is to go to a pick-a-part yard (junk yard where you scrounge for the parts you need) and find one. You won't find one over the counter at the local parts store.

Comment: It is called a "pipe clip"